# Is this question SPAM?

Tags: discussion, spam

I get the feeling [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181050/https-security-issue-on-several-websites) is only asked to place a lot of links. I cannot read czech but it seems to me that many of the links are commercial ones.

The user has only asked this question and seems to have got all his reputation from this question. I am not sure if it should be flagged for spam, but it looks fishy.

Comment: The user has participated on multiple sites, and has 670 reputation on Mathematics. Does not fit the profile of a spammer.

Comment: This sounds convincing. Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: thanks for highlighting this for review - it does indeed look fine, though

Answer (score 3):

You are right that a large collection of URLs is a sign that something could be fishy. However, in this case, I think that all is fine. The links do indeed exhibit a specific problem described in the question. That leads me to believe that it's not spam.

Comment: I just wonder how they got selected and why that many. If they are hosted by the asker I would at least understand, but he seems not to know the configuration so they are probably not.

Comment: @allo Deliberately misconfiguring servers so you can post a question about it on SE seems like a very inefficient way to spam.

Comment: Who knows ... If I would have been sure I would have flagged it, so I rather asked for more opinions here.

Comment: @allo Absolutely, you are always welcome to bring things to meta. :-)